# Load Balancer with Apache HTTPD

Tags: apache, webserver, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I'm struggling to set up a an Apache httpd load balancer in front of a couple of application servers. This is my configuration:

```
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>

    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8080
    BalancerMember http://remote-svr:8080
    ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
    ProxySet stickysession=JESSIONIDSSO
</Proxy>

<Location /balancer-manager>
   SetHandler balancer-manager
</Location>

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain http://127.0.0.1:8080 localhost
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain http://remote-svr:8080 localhost
```

I'm not sure the last 2 lines do anything, although one of the many examples I've looked at online used them, so I added them to see if it fixed my problem (it didn't).

The issue is that if I comment out either of the BalancerMember lines eg:

```
    #BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8080
    BalancerMember http://remote-svr:8080
```

Then the behaviour from a user perspective is fine, however when both members are active, the behaviour is wrong.

The application initially displays a login screen, however when both load balancers are active, the user on submitting their username and password just get redirected back to the login screen again, maybe the session is being lost somewhere. Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

EDIT - NOW WORKING

for reference, this setup now seems to work:

```
ProxyRequests off
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>

    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8080 route=localServer
    BalancerMember http://remote-svr:8080 route=remoteServer
    ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>

<Location /balancer-manager>
   SetHandler balancer-manager
</Location>

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
```

Note the 'route' attribute for the individual nodes needs to be set on the nodes themselves (server.xml in this case, as the servers run JBoss). JSESSIONID worked ok as the sticky session cookie for individual applications but there is more than one application on each server, and the user needs to use the same node for all.

Comment: If you suspect that the stickiness is broken maybe trying what is described in the [troubleshooting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#stickyness_troubleshooting) section of the documentation might get you forward?

Comment: You have to enable session sharing between the application servers, otherwise one doesn't know about logins to the other one.

Comment: EJP, session sharing would take quite a bit of modification to the code, which isn't an option at this point. We want to use sticky sessions to avoid this, by making sure any individual user is routed to the same app server each time, but different users will use different app servers.

Comment: Thanks Qben that looks useful - bizarrely after putting in some of the logging for this the config seems to have started working, despite not making any other changes. There may be some other reason it started working but at least it seems ok now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were to guess you probably loose the session due to a typo in this section:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8080
    BalancerMember http://remote-svr:8080
    ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
    ProxySet stickysession=JESSIONIDSSO
</Proxy>
```

`ProxySet stickysession=JESSIONIDSSO` this should probably say `ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONIDSSO`? Or maybe even `JSESSIONID`?

Comment: Thanks, that was definitely wrong, JSESSIONIDSSO should be ok because that cookie is used for Single sign on to multiple applications, but neither JSESSIONIDSSO or JSESSIONID appears to work in the configuration.